# room on the left vs. left room

Tags: usage

I'm wondering if I can say "the left room" instead of "the room on the left".
If not possible, could you explain why? I know we can say left arm, left wing, left foot...
Plz help!

Comment: Can you please include a sentence example?  In some situations, left room is perfectly acceptable.  But maybe not all instances.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Can you tell us some of the context that led you to be uncertain about the phrase "the left room"? You can [edit] your question to provide this information.

Answer (score 3):

You can, if confronted with two rooms side by side. Thing is you rarely are (outside of floor plans and Salvadori Dali paintings). Usually you are confronted with doors that lead to rooms. Hence we say, "room on the left [side of the hallway]".